# About version control in github

Tags: git, controls, version

So basically let's say i created a website both front-end and back-end and uploaded onto Github for a school project. And it need correct implementation
of using the GitFlow branching model plus evidence of regular
commits using a simple branching model . I am struggle to understand this but this is only 10% worth of the marks.I did my work in Node JS.

So the question is if i simply copy the files from my PC to Github. I don't really need to develop branch or use git command for this as it's much easier to do as long as i sort out the code in specific folder for front and back-end and not all in one place. I created folders for each components on my website so it's easier to find and i will upload them to my github regularly to keep track of the files. I don't think the assessor will be able to tell that i have done this and actually follow the git command for this? beacuse github have already done this for us. And i simply did in a easy way than going through the long process .I hope this make sense.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to the community, Ray.

Let's start with the basics. Firstly, you said

> I created folders for each components on my website so it's easier to
>   find

What do you mean by 'components'?. You should keep frontend and backend in different folders in your file system and create 2 different repositories for each of them. It also means you will have 2 different repositories on GitHub. If your app has a monolith structure (to explain basically: your frontend and backend apps are one single huge app, not two different and separated app which talks with each other on the network layer.) you can have one single repository for the app.

> I don't really need to develop branch or use git command for this as
>   it's much easier

If you are the only one developer of the project, sometimes it may feel like you are overengineering while trying to work with all these develop, feature branches. I know this feeling. But when you start working on more complex features which need to be developed parallelly with some other features, or if your team grows, you will understand the importance of having feature and develop branches.

> I don't think the assessor will be able to tell that i have done this
>   and actually follow the git command for this? because github have
>   already done this for us. And i simply did in a easy way than going
>   through the long process

GitHub, (actually git's itself, under the hood), keeps track of every commits, branches, tags and so on. So, it may be very easy to say if a repository follows a branching strategy or just committing everything to master all the time.

If you use an external tool to simplify GitFlow usage, you can use git-flow-avh tool explained here: https://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/
Thanks to this tool, you don't have to worry about all feature/release/develop branches. Just use it like this and it will create/delete/merge all required branches for you:

```
git flow feature start MYFEATURE
git flow feature stop MYFEATURE
```

Comment: imgur.com is forbidden in my country (facepalm...) , so I couldn't see your screenshots. I never used GitHub's drag&drop feature and but you can not 'upload' files to GitHub without committing them. So probably GitHub will create the commit for you automatically.